# join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function' problem

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on my first website, but I am experiencing some issues such as this one:

join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'function'.

I think it has something to do with views.py but I don't really know how to solve it.

Here's the code:

```
def translator_view(request):

    def translator(phrase):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper:
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper:
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper:
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper:
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        return translation
    return render(request, translator, 'main/translator.html')
```

Comment: I think you should try your best to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and more explicit error message.

Comment: What is the full error message? What line is it on? I don't see a single `.join` in the text so it must be in some library function you are using.

Comment: I think the problem is putting two functions together

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your code. Specifically the "isupper" part has no parenthesis.

Should be:

```
if letter.isupper():
```